# iOS Method Declaration Troubles

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
- (void)alertStatus {

    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Log In"
                                                        message:@"Please enter your username and password"
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];

}
```

This is the .m file

```
    import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface ViewController : UIViewController

    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtPassword;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtUserName;


    - (IBAction) LoginClicked:(id)sender;

    @end
```

This is the .h file, can somebody help me to understand how to declare this method please.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't clear what you're asking.

You want to have a public method alertStatus that can be called from outside?

So just add this line just below the declaration of LoginClicked:

```
- (void)alertStatus;
```

(Note that method names should always start with a lower-case letter, so LoginClicked should be named loginClicked.)

Note that from any class that wants to call methods in ViewController, you need to add the line

```
#import "ViewController.h"
```

At the top of your .m file.

Comment: That is what I tried and it is still saying it is undeclared, it is because it is within another method called "-(IBAction) loginClicked". So therefore the real question I am asking is how do you declare a method within another method?

Comment: Method within another method? You don't. The only language I can think of that supports local functions is PASCAL, and I haven't programmed in Pascal since Mac OS 7. Post the code where you're trying to call alertStatus, as well as how you import the header for your view controller.

Comment: @DuncanC, many languages do allow nested functions: Ruby, Python, Scala. with language extensions even C.

Comment: I worked it out now Duncan, calling my method within a method was incorrect. I didn't realise so until I went over the logic behind the program. Thanks for your help =]

Comment: Can you post an answer to your question explaining what was wrong, then accept your own answer?